# Fun but appropriate Christmas gift to give influential professors.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264371/fun-but-serious-mathematics-books-to-gift-advanced-undergraduates)...

**Background**

A friend and I have been meeting informally with a retired professor to do math on a weekly basis for several semesters now. He is a dear mentor to both of us. We would like to get him a Christmas present, but he is a very private person and rarely discusses his home life, so we know almost nothing about him outside of his mathematical interests. We could get him a book, but chances are good that he would already have it. (His library is enormous, and he's always bringing in obscure texts.)

**Some possibilities:**

- A copy of [The Emperor's Club](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008NFR4)? This is a movie about a teacher and his influence on his students. I'm worried that might be a bit cheesy or inappropriate.
- Something mathematical, but more "popular" that he is less likely to have, like a film or a mathematics-strewn crime novel. (No textbooks!)
- A pie with a $\pi$ carved in the crust.

We're really stumped.

Comment: I vote for pie.  But I will always vote for pie.

Comment: You mentioned the pie with $\pi$ carved in the crust.  My family has a pie plate (from somewhere on the web... I think Signals?) that has the first several (I don't know how many, but probably around 30-50) digits of $\pi$ painted on the rim of the plate.  It also has the Greek letter $\pi$ in the center of the pan.

Comment: If I might make a suggestion. I don't know the man, but the heartfelt words you expressed above say it all. If it were me, I would love to hear that from someone I've helped. Perhaps finding a wonderful inspirational quote and then personalizing that with both your heartfelt sentiments would be worth gold to someone as they feel like they continue to pass on their good deeds! "What you have been obliged to discover by yourself leaves a path in your mind which you can use again when the need arises." - G. C. Lichtenberg

Comment: Personally I hate math-kitch gifts like $\pi$ memorabilia.  I would think twice about that one unless you're sure he would like that type of thing.

Comment: I think @Amzoti hit the nail on the head: You might like the first quote on my profile page; but your own words, accompanying such a quote, will be the heart of such a gift!

Comment: I agree with Alexander Gruber - [especially since $\pi$ is the wrong number to care about](http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto).

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Does this fall under math-kitch?  (Math clock) http://www.signals.com/cgi-bin/hazel.cgi?action=DETAIL&ITEM=HH6134

Comment: @anorton I hate to be a downer, but yes, very much so.

Comment: A mathematical clock should have a $0$ at the "$3$ o'clock" position, and the hands should run backwards.

Comment: I tend to agree with @Amzoti. If either of you has any skill at calligraphy (or knows someone who has), that would be a nice extra touch. (If you know someone in the Society for Creative Anachronism, that would be one place to ask after a calligrapher.)

Comment: @Amzoti Please consider posting your comment as an answer so that it can be on the same "level" as the other answers. IMO your comment is by far the best answer so far.

Comment: @treble done - thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I might make a suggestion.

I don't know the man, but the heartfelt words you expressed above say it all. If it were me, I would love to hear that from someone I've helped.

Perhaps finding a wonderful inspirational quote and then personalizing that with both your heartfelt sentiments would be worth gold to someone as they feel like they continue to pass on their good deeds!

I would even go as far as making it an inscription on a plaque of some sort. I would cherish such as thing forever and would display in a place of honor if I received that.

Both of you young people give us all hope!

"What you have been obliged to discover by yourself leaves a path in your mind which you can use again when the need arises." - G. C. Lichtenberg

Regards -A

Comment: Beautiful quote +1 And I couldn't have answered any better than you!

Comment: @amWhy: This was a nice example of a wonderful professor for helping pass it along and for two very nice young people that give me hope! Regards

Answer (score 3):

As a bit of shameless self promotion, might I suggest a [randomly generated book](http://thatsmathematics.com/blog/mathgen-books), produced by [Mathgen](http://thatsmathematics.com/mathgen/).  It's unlikely he already has it!

(Full disclosure: it's my project, but I don't personally profit from book sales; all my proceeds are donated to the AMS.)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a serious suggestion. [Math and Sex](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1741141591) has always been loved by everyone I have given it to. Nope there is nothing inappropriate in the book but the title does get everyone's attention. It is my favorite gift to give. I have given a copy to everyone.