# Good non-textbook math books

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I'm looking into learning math partially by reading, I have and am currently reading books by Dover publishing. I like these books because they don't use the formulaic textbook layout and rather provide insight into the why **and** how of the content. Does anyone else know any good mathematics books that are similar (preferably in any kind of Math, Logic or Physics)

Comment: What level (high school, beginning undergraduate math major, etc)?

Comment: beggining undergrad, math minor

Comment: I think you'll find most math books are like what you want. Except those texts which are required for people who are not really interested in math. The formulaic approach is needed because the audience is unwilling to learn anything not on the test. So, just stay away from the really expensive required texts and you should do just fine. Dover, while good, sometimes put you in contact with forgotten notation. So I would caution you to do research on each topic you read, choose the right book for a given topic. This site helps with that.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook so pretty much play it by topic?

Comment: Right. Search this site to see what has been said before, there is usually some page with a nice list. Maybe it gives you an idea for a question which is slightly different so you can further refine the search.... I usually can find nice books from universitext or springer etc.. used on major undergrad topics for 20-40 dollars, but on occasion you need to buy some 80 dollar text because it's better. For example, I think the cost of smooth manifolds by Lee (2012 edition makes it costly) is worth it, as opposed to say Bishop and Goldberg for $5 in dover. I do use some dovers as course texts

Comment: You might like [Visual Complex Analysis](http://www.amazon.com/Visual-Complex-Analysis-Tristan-Needham/dp/0198534469).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264371/fun-but-serious-mathematics-books-to-gift-advanced-undergraduates

Comment: Introduction To Complex Analysis: College Mathematics Series - Zeev Nehari

Answer (score 2):

Here are two personal favorites,

- [The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052154677X) by J. Michael Steele
- [A book of Abstract Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486474178) by Charles Pinter

Comment: I agree that *The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class* and *A Book of Abstract Algebra* are well worth considering. I would be interested in knowing what you particularly like about them.